# How to make layout using css and divs?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a problem with making layout for my website. Basically, I don't know CSS, because of this can someone write a css for divs which will look like this? I haven't found any template which could solve my problem. I've found this

```
.left
{
   float: left;
   width: 15%;
}
.right
{
    float:right;
    width: 85%;
}
.right_bottom
{
    float:right;
    width: 85%;
    height: 4%;
}
```

But it doesn't work
[image]

---

---

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: yes, i'll edit my question

Comment: Check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) for your solution. They have good tutorials.

Comment: perhaps you want to read this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du4bt1x6/1/)

css code  :

```
.mainDiv {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
.topDiv {
    height: 15%;
    background-color: black;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 85%;
    background-color:red;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width: 85%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color:green;
}
.right_bottom {
    float:right;
    width: 85%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="mainDiv">
   <div class="topDiv"></div>
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
   <div class="right_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that it'll really help, you'll need to know css but here you go.

```css
header {
  background: red;
  height: 120px;
}
section, aside {
  height: 1000px;
}
article {
  height: 850px;
}
section {
  background: blue;
}
aside {
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
  width: 30%;
}
footer {
  width: 70%;
  background: green;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header></header>
  <aside></aside>
  <article></article>
  <footer></footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry... Just realised you said divs! oops.